# Are all fields of the instance of the constant class still final or constant values if they are instantiated without the const key word?

Tags: dart

What happens if a constant constructor is outside of a constant context and is invoked without const, are all fields of the instance of the class still final or constant values? I know that it will be a non-constant object.

```
MaterialApp(); // Do NOT create a constant
```

Answer (score 0):

The `const` variables wrapped by the `MaterialApp` are still `const`.

It's a good practice to set a value as `const` when it is possible

Comment: Sometimes we pass the arguments to an object, which is already a constant. Lint will complain about that with a blue warning in Visual Studio Code `unnessesary_const` for example if we pass constant objects to constant object.

Comment: Why does the documentation still state that it's a non-constant object?

Comment: The warning can be about the don't use `const` redundantly. You can read a little more [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-const-redundantly)

Answer (score 0):

A class that has a `const` constructor must have only `final` (non-reassignable) fields, and that is part of the class interface (i.e., the class provides only getters for those fields and no setters).

Whether or not an *instance* of that class is a compile-time constant does not change that.

Comment: Why does the documentation state that it's a _non-constant_ object whereby its fields are still `final`?

Comment: @NgocDat A "constant object" means only that it's a compile-time constant.  An object with `final` fields is not necessarily a compile-time constant (and furthermore, an object with `final` fields is not necessarily immutable either; its members could have methods that mutate them).

Comment: Why must a class with a `const` constructor have only `final` fields, not `const`? I have read the 'must' in the constant constructor section in the documentation. I don't know why these are the rules.

Comment: @NgocDat That a class has a `const` constructor does not *require* that all callers invoke the constructor in a `const` context.  It does not make sense for its members to be declared `const`; what would happen if a caller invoked a non-`const` constructor?  Dart additionally does not allow non-`static` `const` members either.

Answer (score 0):

A `const` constructor works just as any other constructor.

The `const` constructor has some extra requirements on the initializer list (potentially constant expressions only) and body (no body!), and puts some restrictions on the surrounding class (all fields must be `final`).

Any class can satisfy those restrictions, whether it has a const constructor or not.

When a `const` constructor is invoked as non-`const` (not inside a `const` context and no `const` in front of it), it works just like any other constructor, on a class that works like any other class. You can completely ignore the `const` then, and just treat the class and constructor as you otherwise would.

A non-redirecting generative constructor (the *real* constructor which actually initializes the object state, as opposed to redirecting or factory constructors) will still initialize the class fields. Those fields are still final.

What differs between the `const` invocation and the non-`const` invocation of the constructor is not what the constructor does, but what happens before and after.

In a `const` invocation, *all* arguments must also be constant expressions, evaluating to constant values. The potentially constant expressions of the initializer list are also only able to create constant values.
This ensures that *all* the final fields are initialized with other constant values, which again ensures that the resulting object is deeply immutable.
The restrictions on having no body and very restricted initializer list expressions are to ensure that only very simple user-code expressions and specific platform library methods can be called during evaluation. That allows the compiler to pretend to evaluate the constructor before it's done compiling the program.

Also, after a `const` invocation, the resulting object is *canonicalized*.
If the compiler has already created another constant object of the same type,
with the same (identical, after canonicalization) values in every field, it throws away the new object and uses the existing one.
That is the reason for requiring the fields to be `final`. If the object was mutable, canonicalization wouldn't make sense, because you can tell the difference between two objects by mutating one.
When the objects are immutable, canonicalization doesn't change program behavior.

Those two difference are visible:

```dart
class C {
  final List<int> list;
  const C(this.list);
}
void main() {
  const c1 = C([1]);
  var c2 = const C([1]);
  print(identical(c1, c2)); // true
  print(identical(c1.list, c2.list)); // true

  var v1 = C(c1.list); // Deeply immutable, not canonicalized.
  print(identical(c1, v1)); // false

  var v2 = C([1]);
  print(identical(c1, v2)); // false
  print(identical(v1, v2)); // false
  v2.list.add(42);
  print(v2.list); // [1, 42] // Not deeply immutable.
}
```

Comment: Why must a class with a const constructor have only final fields, not const? I have read the 'must' in the constant constructor section in the documentation. I don't know why these are the rules.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Instance fields *cannot* be `const`, because it wouldn't mean anything, since you can read getters in a constant expression anyway. So they are final because that allows canonicalizing constant objects with the same state. If the objects were mutable, it wouldn't be enough to be *created* with the same state to make the objects indistinguishable.